# Baxter robot setup in Linux

Tags: ros, ssh, baxter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm a new user for the Baxter robot. Currently, I'm trying to setup the working environment on my computer by following the Baxter Wiki provide instruction. but until to the step of Verify Development Workstation Ping, I faced one problem. I can identify my ROS_IP but when I going to SSH to Baxter and verify the ability to communicate with my development PC, it shows me Persimmon denied. this is the code I follow:

```
$ ssh ruser@<our ROS Master>

# Password: rethink

# Example:
$ ssh ruser@011303P0017.local
```

of course, my ROS Master was different with the example.
Then after that, it asks me to enter the password which is the rethink, but I try three times. in the end, shows me Persimmon denied.

Does anyone have the same problem before?
By the way, I'm using ubuntu 14.04 64bit indigo and robot system version was 0.0.28

Thank you

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234786/baxter-robot-setup-in-linux/) by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2016-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The obvious first thing to check is whether that username & password combination is actually correct. Has someone changed it without letting you know?

In any case this is probably something you should contact Rethink about: they have quite an extensive [support site](http://www.rethinkrobotics.com/training-support/) and should be able to help you.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-05-20**:
I had tried to find whether anyone had change the password nd username before, but I cannot retrieve back the history who had handled the robot before.

In addition, I had sent the email to the support team ask for help, but they still not reply me yet.

Anyway, I really appreciate your advice